# How to notify user before loading Interstitial Ad

Tags: android, admob, preload, interstitial

Currently in my application I am showing ad when user click on button or move to new activity, what I want to do is notify user before loading ad. I want to show message like **Ad is loading...!** and after 2-3 sec that msg should disappear. In short I want to show dialog on preload of ad. I was trying this with help of alert msg but that is not working, I am not sure where we need to add alert dialog.

Please help...!

Thanks in Advance...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by using following code

```
/* Show your dialog */

    ShowDailog();

/* following code will run after 3000ms */

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            showInterstitial();
                        }

                    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Thread` that count down for x sec, every sec the textView will change (it will be a number) and then the user will get the feeling of counts down

```
public CountDownThread extend Thread { 

private int mTotalNum;
private CountDownListener mCuntDownListener;


public CountDownThread(int totalNum, CountDownListener countDownListener) {
   this.mTotalNum = totalNum
   this.mCountDownListener = countDownListener
}

@Override
public void run(){
  while (mTotalNum > 0) {
      try {
        sleep(1000);
      }catch (InterruptedException e){
     //
      }
      --mTotalNum
   } 
  mCuntDownListener.onCountDownThreadDone()
}
```

In your activity:

1) You need to implement `CountDownListener` (When you implement the `CountDownListener` you will have to implement the `onCountDownThreadDone()` method, there you need to implement your `dailog box`).
2) In addition,  you will need to call to `CountDownThread(3, this)`
(`3` is your display time in sec, `this` is the listener).

This is the `interface`:

```
public interface CountDownListener {
    void onCountDownThreadDone();
}
```

After the count down (in your case 3 sec) is finished, the `onCountDownThreadDone()` method will be called (look at `run()` method in `CountDownThread` class). Then the implementation of your `dailog box` will appear (you implement it in your `Activity`).

Comment: sorry can you please explain more? or any example will help me for better understanding. I want to just display `dialog box` for 3-4 sec with no action, so user can understand `ad` is loading.

Comment: Hi, i've edit my answer... hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CountDownTimer as below, First, toast message show up then 3 sec.(3000msec) later your ad code will run

```
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ad is loading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {  // runs after 2 sec. (2000 msec.)
                // This is the place where you call your interstitial ad.
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: sorry can you please explain more? or any example will help me for better understanding. I want to just display `dialog box` for 3-4 sec with no action, so user can understand `ad` is loading.

Comment: @MagicduetoLogic Edited my answer.